# PHP Search Files

Tags: php, ajax, file, glob

So I'm doing a file system using metro ui css and, I want to do a file searching system. I have some code already and I'm using AJAX.

I don't see any point of showing ajax code, as its same as everything.

PHP:

```
<?php 

sleep(2);
if(!$_POST) {
    die('hell no');
}

include('../config.php');

$where_post = $_POST['where']; 
$text = $_POST['text']; 

if($where_post == 'Anywhere') {
    $where = 'folders/*'; 
}
elseif ($where_post == 'CMS') {
    $where = 'folders/CMS';
}
elseif ($where_post == 'Emulator') {
    $where = 'folders/Emulator';
}
elseif ($where_post == 'Full Packs') {
    $where = 'folders/Full Packs';
}
elseif ($where_post == 'Furni Packs') {
    $where = 'folders/Furni Packs';
}
elseif ($where_post == 'SQL') {
    $where = 'folders/SQL';
}
elseif ($where_post == 'SWF') {
    $where = 'folders/SWF';
}
$files = glob("../".$where."/*". $text ."*.*", GLOB_NOCHECK);

if(count($files) > 0){
     foreach($files as $file){                  
        var_dump($files);
             }
}

 ?>
```

So my question is, how can I show it? I don't have a design atm, so I'll implement it later..

Thanks!

Comment: You could try `echo`. Please improve your question, it is unclear what you want to show or what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is, I can't see the files. It's not working, when I `echo $files;` it shows `array ( )`  and when I do `var_dump($files);` it just shows the raw thing, not processing the search. @Jeffrey

Comment: *it just shows the raw thing* The `GLOB_NOCHECK` return the search pattern if no files matching it were found. Thus, perhaps there are no files found? Is the path correctly? how about a simple `var_dump( glob("*") )` does it return the files you expect?

Comment: `var_dump(glob('*'));` won't work because searching files under `/folder/$where_post` and search.php is under `system/js/` so... 
Removed GLOB_NOCHECK and it returns nothing, but it should return at least 1 file because: http://prntscr.com/gg643n

Comment: dumping `glob('*')` should show you what the working directory is of the PHP file (or use `getcwd();`). Than you have to figure out how that directory relates to the `/folders/` directory, because I think the current relation of just one folder up, might be incorrect. Since I cannot see the full paths you are using, i cannot help.